# Only move the "z" axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this Recoil script, the only problem is that the code moves my gun to all of the axes but I only want to move my gun on the **Z-axis**. I couldn't find any solution for it. Thanks! Here is the code:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 
 public class Recoil : MonoBehaviour {
 
     public Vector3 hipPos;
     public Vector3 zoomPos;
     public float speed = 4f;
 
     void Update () {
         if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
             transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localPosition, zoomPos, Time.deltaTime * speed);
             transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localPosition, hipPos, Time.deltaTime * speed);
         }
         else {
             transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localPosition, hipPos, Time.deltaTime * speed);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: So keep the x and y and keep on the the z

Comment: Yes. But I already got a perfect answer to my question. Thanks anyways. 

Comment: Well the answer wasn’t there when I wrote it. So you could argue someone took my comment and did it for you. Im not accusing Seth of it though.  It doesn’t seem like you tried though

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the gun to move towards the desired z position, but keep the x and y positions the same.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 
 public class Recoil : MonoBehaviour {
 
     public Vector3 hipPos;
     public Vector3 zoomPos;
     public float speed = 4f;
     private Vector3 localPosition 
 
     void Update () {
         if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
             transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localPosition, new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, transform.localPosition.y, zoomPos.z), Time.deltaTime * speed);
             transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localPosition, new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, transform.localPosition.y, hipPos.z) , Time.deltaTime * speed);
         }
         else {
             transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localPosition, new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, transform.localPosition.y, hipPos.z), Time.deltaTime * speed);
         }
     }
 }
```

To understand how lerp works, refer to the Unity documentation for it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html).